# Как узнать код символа в кодировке Windows-1251?

Tags: c#, кодировка

Есть строка `"пример"`. Как получить код каждого её символа?

(Кодировка — Windows-1251: “A” – 192 , “Б” – 193 и т. д.)

Comment: Никак, потому что в ASCII не существует русских букв.

Comment: @andreymal “A” – 192 , “Б” – 193(ASCII (дес.))

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII  в ASCII не существует русских букв, последний символ ASCII таблицы имеет код 127, там нет никаких 192 или 193.

Comment: странно, значит в формулировке задания какая-то ошибка, спасибо...

Comment: @moonsharm, а чего не 1040 и 1041?

Comment: @moonsharm в ASCII в принципе не существует кодов больше 127 (это семибитная кодировка). Показанные вами коды 192 и 193 — это кодировка CP1251, которая не имеет никакого отношения к ASCII (точнее, она является надмножеством ASCII, но это не то же самое что и «чистая» ASCII)

Comment: @andreymal отлично, прошу прощения за неточность. А можно как-нибудь привести значение символа к коду из данной таблицы?

Comment: Можно использовать что-то вроде `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251").GetBytes("пример")` чтобы получить `bytes[]`, а потом уже из этого массива байтов вытянуть интересующие циферки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “A” – 192 , “Б” – 193(ASCII (дес.))

> https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII в ASCII не существует русских букв, последний символ ASCII таблицы имеет код 127, там нет никаких 192 или 193.

Как было подмечено, `“A” – 192 , “Б” – 193` - это кодировка Windows-1251.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
    string text = "пример";
    byte[] bytes = win1251.GetBytes(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{text[i]} = {bytes[i]}");
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
п = 239
р = 240
и = 232
м = 236
е = 229
р = 240
```

---

```
string text = "АБ";
```

```
А = 192
Б = 193
```

*Этот код будет работать только с однобайтовыми кодировками, так что для многобайтовых типа UTF-8 его использовать не стоит, придется дорабатывать.*

Comment: возможно глупый вопрос, но.... а нельзя ли взять просто `Char` и привести его к `Int` ?

Comment: @Andrew тогда получится UTF-16, а не Win1251 :)